# How can I recover my Ubuntu OS after a failed upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, shutdown

Well, I was upgrading my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and suddenly the power went off. I was in the installation stage and only a bit of it was done. Now when I boot into Ubuntu, it shows a command 
line that shows that it can't read the files or something. I please need to recover my system and
most importantly my files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Online upgrade or off a boot medium (CD, USB..)? You will be wanting a bootable disc of some sort, and ideally a USB drive you can backup your files on. Do you have these, or access to another PC if not?

Comment: Yes, one of 2GB free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you boot off the bootable CD/USB & select the 'Try Ubuntu' option you will have a working system; plug the USB drive in, it should mount; you should also have an icon for your main (corrupted) drive, which you can double-click & it, too should mount. Assuming it does, you can navigate to your files & copy them safely to the USB drive.
If this goes OK, you'll almost certainly need to re-do the installation - I would unmount & disconnect the backup drive first. That's it..

If you get permission errors, or something won't mount, open a terminal:

`sudo -i` to get root permissions for all the next bit.

If drives mounted, skip over the following to **Copying**.

`mkdir /media/ubuntu/drive1 /media/ubuntu/drive2` - we need to create mount points. Then, we need to identify your drives:

`dmesg | tail` will tell you where it put your USB drive - likely sdb or similar.

Your main drive should be /dev/sda_ ; _ may be 1 if there's no Windows etc around.
If you're not sure, run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` which should list the partitions for you. You can probably work out which is your home directory by sizes if it's not obvious - that's the one we want. `fdisk -l` with no drive will list all drives on your system.

Once you're confident you have the right drives, (I'll use sda1 for your old files, sdb1 for the new USB - you use whatever you found..) type:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu/drive1
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/ubuntu/drive2
```

**Copying:**

`shopt -s dotglob` if you want to keep hidden files, eg .gnupg/, .mozilla/ - better to do it than not.

`cp -R -preserve=all /media/ubuntu/whatever-it-called-your-old-drive/home/yourname/* /media/ubuntu/whatever-it-called-your-USB/`   # This will take some time, but will copy all your files under your old userid, to your backup drive.

We now have the backup & can proceed to re-install to OS - unmount & disconnect the USB first.

Finally:

Once the re-installation is done, you have a system with an almost empty home directory. Just copy some or all of your files back off the USB. If you use the `shopt -s dotglob` command it will take all your emails & passwords etc back over too; but may overwrite some system files, so I always take a (renamed) copy of the new blank home as well, just in case!

If the new installation assigned you a new userid, you may find you can't log in due to not owning your own files.

```
cd /home/
shopt -s dotglob
sudo chown -R you:you you
```

should fix that.